# Java class which requires using interface if you want to use it's method

Tags: java, sorting, interface

If you want to use sort() method from Arrays class you MUST implement Comparable  interface. This is a really good idea - you can't sort objects if they're not compatible. So you can't sort if you can't compare it's references. In this case interface is used like compatibility checker.

The question is - how can I make:

- a class with a method (may do something with 2 objects)
- interface that checks if this 2 objects are comatible (have compatible references)
- add to my class "must use this interface" rule, so you can't use this class method without implementing specific interface, just like Comparable class does ?

Example:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
//fields
//setters, getters

    // this method must be implemented to use Arrays.sort()
    public int compareTo(Employee other) {
        return Double.compare(salary, other.salary);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your requirements here? It sounds like you want to be able to determine at run-time whether a class should be implementing `Comparable` or not. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't completely understand your requirements; I'd prefer an example of what you want _your_ class to look like, and examples of uses of your class that you do or don't want to disallow.  Offhand, I'm guessing that you will want to use generics `<T extends YourInterface>` or use `instanceof` to check at run time.

Comment: "You can't use this class method without implementing specific interface". What do you mean? Who do you want to enforce that implements the interface? The client of the class or the class itself? Can you reformulate this question?

Comment: Yes, what I mean is: if you wan't to use sort() you must implement comparable. So the question is - can I determine, that you must use some X interface if you want to use my X method.

Comment: Without this interface I get error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Employee cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Answer (score 2):

An interface can't *check* anything.

You can write this:

```
interface One { }
interface Two { }

SomeType someMethod(One one, Two two) { ... }
```

The compiler will not allow anybody's code to call someMethod(a, b) unless it can prove that a is an instance of some class that `implements One` and b is an instance of some class that `implements Two`.

Is that what you're asking?

---

Added Info:

`Arrays.sort(Object[] a)` is different:  The *compiler* does not know whether the elements in the array implement the Comparable interface or not.  That information is not available until run-time.

I don't know how java.util.Arrays.sort() does it, but you you want to do the same thing in your own code, you can write this:

```
interface One { }
interface Two { }

SomeType someMethod(Object oneAsObject, Object twoAsObject) {
    One one = One.class.cast(oneAsObject);
    Two two = Two.class.cast(twoAsObject);
    ...
}
```

This is different from my first example because the compiler will let you pass in any type of object, but the function will throw a ClassCastException at run time if the wrong type of object is passed.

But why would you want to wait until run time to find an error that you could have found at compile time? (e.g., why wait until the lander is descending toward the Martian surface to find a fatal flaw that you could have found before it was launched?)

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment:

> Yes, what I mean is: if you wan't to use sort() you must implement comparable. So the question is - can I determine, that you must use some X interface if you want to use my X method.

You could do this with an abstract class.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void methodA();
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass implements MyInterface {
    public void methodB(
        System.out.println("Pop");
    )
}
```

Anything that wants to use `methodB` must extend `MyAbstractClass`, and therefore must implement `MyInterface`.